# Option Strict and DefaultValueAttribute

Tags: vb.net

Having just spent the past several hours trying to work out why my Xml Serialization code was not working. Consider the following:

```
<DefaultValueAttribute(False)>
Public Property UserName() As String
```

Why is this allowed regardless of option strict being on (or not)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that VS does not type check default values for VB.NET, regardless of OptionStrict or not.

`<DefaultValueAttribute(False)>` is valid because the attribute definition is really a constructor and not a type definition, as such it's type is `DefaultValueAttribute` and not a return type of `boolean`. Furthermore the `.Value` property of the `DefaultValueAttribute` is of type `Object` and hence it's type cannot be compared either, as such the very existence of `DefaultValueAttribute` violates `Option Strict On` and hence `Option Strict` ignored for the scope of `DefaultValue` Attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple. The `DefaultValueAttribute` has an overload which accepts boolean values so it will work with or without `Option Strict` on.

Check this page for more information [DefaultValueAttribute Class](http://www.google.com.gh/#hl=en&source=hp&q=defaultvalueattribute+msdn+documentation&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=e87309136c57ecc0).